# ajax success function not firing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have made a login form which utilises php, ajax and mysql, the php code seems to work fine as it says that when the user credentials are entered a success message is echoed on the screen.

However the ajax is supposed to take this and process it and open up the index.php page which it fails to do so. However the ajax does work to an extent as my "checking..." message appears as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please find the code below.

**loginajax.js**

```
function chk_ajax_login_with_php() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


    var params = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var url = "login.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function () {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'checking...';
        },
        complete: function () {

        },
        success: function (html) {
            if (html == "success") {
                window.location = 'index.php';
            }

        }

    });

}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

require "header.php"; 

 try 
{
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "dbpassword");
    if(!$connection) {   
      die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());   
    }   
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("dbname",$connection);   
    if (!$db_select) {   
      die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error());   
     }   

   }catch (Exception $e){
     error_log(" DB Error: ".$e->getMessage());
   }

  if($_POST){

     $username=$_POST['username'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE userID ='".$username."' AND  userPass ='".md5($password)."'") or die(mysql_error());
     $res=mysql_num_rows($sql);




 if($res>0){

     $rs_login=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
     $uid=$rs_login['user_id'];
     $_SESSION['sess_uid']=$uid;
     echo "success";

  } 

     else{

    echo "invalid username or password";

  }




  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Are u sure the server side script is returning echo "success";

Comment: Try `echo "success";exit;` in `login.php`

Comment: Hi, yeah I tried echoing success and the message appeared.

Comment: However the issue still remains and the page doesn't get replaced with the index.php page.

Comment: Is there any whitespace before/after the word `success`?

Comment: There is no white space from looking at my code

Comment: So if you take `loginajax.js` completely out of the equation and submit your form normally then what output do you get on-screen?

Comment: can you provide header and response from developer console of any browser.

Comment: when I take out loginajax.js out, I get a success message due to the php code : if($res>0){

     $rs_login=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
     $uid=$rs_login['user_id'];
     $_SESSION['sess_uid']=$uid;
     echo "success";

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should debug it!

```
success: function(html) {
      console.log(html);
      return false;
      //if(html=="success"){
      //window.location = 'index.php';
      //}
 }
```

here you will be sure that success is fired because of the console.log and you see login.php output.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, it seems when using the debugging solution that the success message still appears which is defined in the php. It doesn't seem to be reaching the success function.

Comment: complete() must be call after success()... if you dont use it, then just delete it!

Comment: I have removed the complete function following what you said, it hasn't made an impact, I appreciate your advice however, I didn't realise that it should be omitted.

Comment: well, I think beforeSend is not used in the good way.
"A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent."
Just try your ajaxcall without beforeSend.

Comment: without before send, the checking message disappears as expected, however the rest of the ajax fails to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jquery.js file. 
if not, include the following line in  tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have this included in my header.php file which is included in my require statement.

Answer (score 0):

It probably in error.

The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
 .done(function(html) {
     console.log(html);
 })
 .fail(function(html) {
     console.log(html);
 })
 .always(function(html) {
     console.log(html);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `html=="success"`, put this in the if condition:

```
html.responseText=="success"
```

responseText contains the response from the server in string format. If you are not expecting XML or JSON format your should use always responseText.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, it didn't work in this case but I will heed to this advice in the future.

Comment: Then try the same but removing the dataType property of the ajax request.

Comment: Or you can make it better and return a JSON object from the server and catch the response as a JSON. This is the cleanest solution to your problem.

Comment: I will take this under consideration, I have worked little with JSON but I have a go today!

Comment: JSON is the native javascript object notation, so if you work with it you take a lot of advantages, specially getting things through an API, which is directly, you don't have to transform the data returned from the server.